# SolrJ invalid content-type

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Whenever I execute a query on Solr, even the most simple query `*:*`, I get the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Error executing query
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:100)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
at com.atmire.dspace.versioning.ModificationLogger.search(ModificationLogger.java:294)
at com.atmire.dspace.versioning.ModificationsReporter.main(ModificationsReporter.java:92)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ParseException: Invalid content type: 
at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.parse(ContentType.java:233)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:496)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:210)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:206)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:91)
... 3 more
```

Though the same query runs fine against when using the webclient or using curl:

`curl http://localhost:8080/solr/versioning/select\?q\=\*%3A\*\&wt\=json\&indent\=true`

I'm quite confused as to why the query would not work from java. The relevant java code

```
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery().setQuery("*:*");
    query.setRows(rpp).setStart(start);
    QueryResponse queryResponse = solr.query(query);
    return queryResponse.getResults();
```

It seems that SolrQuery nor solr have the option to explicitely set the Content-Type, at least not that I could find in the API docs. Furthermore, I'm quite surprised that if I would have to speicfy the Content-Type, that it actually works with curl even when I don't add `wt=json`. Though I suspect that that is for the response, not the request.

Comment: Have you check if the Solr log on the server side (and not for Solr) generates an error? This might happen if SolrJ doesn't get a binary response as expected (SolrJ uses serialized POJOs IIRC). The Solr log should also show you exactly which request Solr received from SolrJ.

Comment: Would you add the portion of your code how the `server` is created? Probably you are using something embedded, but you are targeting something remote.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like maybe it is not actually pointing at the Solr server. Can you double check your earlier code and see if you are definitely setting the right host and port (which is not default for you), as well as the right collection.